# Woocommerce Storefront Adding a hover effect to product categories on Home Page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover, storefront

I would like to add a hover effect on the Home Page like here:
http://demo.woothemes.com/?name=galleria&_ga=1.242371650.1503770507.1481544136

I found a way to add a hover effect in product

```
/* Make product in categories glow on hover */
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1e73be;
}
```

But I can't find a way to make this for product categories in the home section.

I use the Storefront Child Theme Master to Edit the Storefront Themes:
https://github.com/stuartduff/storefront-child-theme

Any kind of help is appreciated,

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

You will first need to alter the position and visibility of the h3 titles.

```
ul.products li.product.product-category h3 {
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   padding-top: 25%;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
```

And then make it visible on hover.

```
ul.products li.product.product-category:hover h3 {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

That's as close as I can get to the demo without going into media queries :/

Comment: Actually I would like to add a hover effect in Product Categories in the Home Page. Not products individually. as it is here: http://demo.woothemes.com/?name=galleria&_ga=1.242371650.1503770507.1481544136

Comment: in the product categories with hover effects and the name of categories + quantity of items availeables

Comment: Ah, OK. That is a hidden overlay that is changed to opacity: 1 on hover. If that hidden section is included on your page you should be able to trigger it with:
ul.products li.product:hover .g-product-title { opacity: 1}

Comment: But I would need to see the actual page you are working on to provide a tailored solution

Comment: I've updated my answer there. It's as close I can get to the demo with your sites underlying code

Comment: Something was missed. I updted your answer and I will accepted as good!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135774/discussion-between-hope-and-digedu).